# What is this circular orange spot in GNOME's top bar menu?

Tags: gnome-shell, indicator

My cat walked through the keyboard and now there is this weird orange dot/spot/circle alongside the network, Bluetooth, sound and battery icons:

[image: Alongside with network, Bluetooth, sound and battery notifications, there appears an orange dot.]

What is this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It means that you are **recording your screen**, the keyboard shortcut to start / stop it is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

As [pomsky](https://askubuntu.com/users/480481/pomsky) suggests:
The videos get saved to a default folder, which, in most cases, is your **Videos** directory.

Comment: I have a Cinnamon desktop and it gets saved in my Home folder under the name "cinnamon[date]-[index].webm".

Comment: Thanks, that was it! No surprise my machine was that slow. I had to log off because the shortcuts didn't work, but it was just a glitch fortunately. And now I know how to record a screencast :) Thanks!

Comment: I have the same, but I can't turn it off by CTRL + ALT + Shift + R (then new record video is showing but still orange circle is there). Any other way to turn it off? By terminal probably?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the accepted answer, the orange spot means your screen is being recorded.

I had the problem that I could not turn it off due to a malfunctioning Wayland screencast recording on (GNOME) Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, and was unable to turn it off with Ctrl+Alt+Shift+R (which user Piotr Wasilewicz in a comment mentions too).

I found the solution was to install the C++ wrappers for GStreamer and GLib, after which the dot would go away after stopping to record (via pressing the red stop button on the top-right; Ctrl+Alt+Shift+R still doesn't work).

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamermm-1.0-1 libglibmm-2.4-1v5
```

However, for some reason my GNOME screencast recording produces videos with errors anyway. You can also kill the `gjs` process from System Monitor or similar.

In the end I was able to successfully record my screen with video by logging off, selecting **Ubuntu on Xorg** (from a gear button on the bottom-right of the log-in screen, when you're at the screen where you enter your password), *and* using SimpleScreenRecorder instead of the recorder provided by GNOME.

```
sudo apt-get install simplescreenrecorder
```

GNOME's screen recorder simply doesn't work on my hardware at this moment at least.

I hope this helps others searching how to record the screen on Ubuntu 22.04.